# How to correctly express this sentence?

Tags: word-choice

Yesterday, I met one of my friends. Then, I met another one. This (**another friend**) looked happy and told me good news.

Is it correct to use "This another friend"? If no, how to refer to the other friend?

Comment: You can't say "this another friend", because *friend* is a countable noun, so it needs exactly one determiner, and both *this* and *another* are determiners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could say:

> Yesterday, I met one of my friends. Then, I met another one. This other friend looked happy and told me good news.

Or you could have said:

> Yesterday, I met one of my friends. Then, I met another friend who looked happy and told me good news.

Answer (score 1):

You could phrase it like this;

> Yesterday, I met one of my friends. Then, I met another one. This
>   friend looked happy and told me good news.

The sentences could be more fluent by rephrasing like this:

> Yesterday, I met one of my friends. Then, I met another one, who
>   looked happy and told me some good news.